# django>=1.7 django.setup() is raising AppRegistryNotReady

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a Django project which contains multiple apps and I'm in the middle of migrating this project to Django >=1.7. Model is successfully loaded for all the other app, however, one app keeps running into `AppRegistryNotReady; Models aren't loaded yet`. I googled and the most popular answer was `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xx.settings")`  then `django.setup()` at the `__init__.py` of the problematic app, but these are not helping and even `setup()` raises `AppRegistryNotReady`.

This app hooked with `lamson` which I need to turn on this app in a different way (`lamson start`) than other apps and I guess this is why I have this problem? (i.e. this app can't connect to other apps)

Any suggestion on how to approach this issue?